# Unrecognized repository Scala Plugin Bundled Repository

Tags: scala, sbt

When creating a fresh Scala SBT project in IntelliJ, I get this warning on `sbt reload`:

```
[warn] Unrecognized repository Scala Plugin Bundled Repository, ignoring it
```

I am aware that it is only a warning. What does it mean, and how do I resolve it?

SBT version `1.6.2`,
Scala version `2.12.16`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning usually means there are some leftovers from a previous Scala plugin update which didn't finish successfully. Trying to update or reinstall your Scala plugin should fix the issue. Trying to change your Scala version might also make it go away.

In the end it's a harmless warning; if it does not causes any issue in your program, you can forget about it.

Answer (score 2):

"Repair IDE" in IntelliJ's File menu fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

I have the same warning for quite some time, I have no idea what it means and I ignore it. without experiencing any adverse effects in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Note, the issue is fixed in version 2023.3